# LongListSelector and ContextMenu return wrong item

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have this `LongListSelector` in a page:

```
<Controls:LongListSelector Height="Auto" x:Name="historylist" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  
                                   Background="Black" SelectionChanged="DidPressSelectItem">
            <Controls:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:SearchTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            <toolkit:ContextMenu Opened="ContextMenu_Opened">
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Edit" Click="EditVideo"/>
                            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
.
.
.
.
                   </local:SearchTemplateSelector>
                </DataTemplate>


            </Controls:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

And this is the `EditVideo`

```
private void EditVideo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        VideoItem selectedVideo = (sender as MenuItem).DataContext as VideoItem;
        if (video == null) { return; }

        //Do Stuff

        this.RelodeTableData();
    }
```

And the `RelodeTableData`:

```
private void RelodeTableData()
    {
        System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            searchResults.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < historyRep.historyArray.Count; i++)
            {
                VideoItem item = historyRep.historyArray[i];
                searchResults.Add(item);
            }
        });
    }
```

And the problem is that when the user edit a item and try to edit another item after that he get the last item he edit in `selectedVideo`.

I use the ReloadTableData to refresh the list data after i edit it.

Comment: Is your `searchResults` collection an instance of `ObservableCollection'?

Comment: Yes: ObservableCollection<VideoItem> searchResults = new ObservableCollection<VideoItem>();

Comment: So you mean the right video item is displayed for the user, but wrong DataContext appears inside event handler?

Comment: I found an answer for this, thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok after a lot of searching how to fix this thing. i fount that if i add `Unload` method to the `ContextMenu` and this is clear the DataContext.

```
private void ContextMenu_Unload(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContextMenu conmen = (sender as ContextMenu);
        conmen.ClearValue(FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty);
    }
```